# One horizontal colorbar for seaborn heatmaps subplots and Annot Issue with xticklabels

Tags: python, python-3.x, heatmap, seaborn

I tried to write multiple heatmaps in one figure.
I wrote the below code and I have two questions.

(1) I want the data value in each cell and I don't need the axis labels for each picture. Therefore, I set xticklabels, yticklables, and annot; but they were not reflected in the figure. How should I do?
(2) Can I rotate the color bar? I need one horizontal color bar for this fifure.

I use Python 3.5.2 in Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

%matplotlib notebook

flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
# integral
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
sns.set(font_scale=0.8)
plt.title('integral', fontsize = 1)
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.90, left = 0.1)
sns.heatmap(flights, fmt='d', cmap='gist_gray_r', xticklabels = False, yticklabels = False, annot=True)

#float
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
sns.set(font_scale=0.8)
plt.title('float', fontsize = 1)
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.90, left = 0.1)
sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True, fmt='.2f', cmap='gist_gray_r', xticklabels = False, yticklabels = False)

fig.suptitle('Title for figure', fontsize=20)
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9, left=0.06, bottom=0.08) #後ろ2つ追加
#x label
fig.text(0.5, 0.02, 'year', ha='center', va='center')
#y label
fig.text(0.02, 0.5, 'month', ha='center', va='center', rotation='vertical')

sns.plt.savefig('heatmap.png')
```

[image]

Comment: took me longer than expected, but I've just edited my answer to properly suit your question!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> (1) I want the data value in each cell and I don't need the axis
>   labels for each picture. Therefore, I set xticklabels, yticklables,
>   and annot; but they were not reflected in the figure. How should I do?

It's a [recent fixed issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/837) that when `xticklabels = False` or `yticklabels = False`, `annot = True` doesn't work. A workaround is to set `xticklabels` and `yticklabels` both to a list of an empty string `[""]`.

I made an adjustment declaring the subplots axis with `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)`, which is better for understanding the code. I set all axes labels to `""` with the likes of: `ax1.set_ylabel('')`, so after cleaning, we can make the labels we want, instead of those auto-generated with `sns.heatmap`. Also, the labels in the figure are better generated this way than manually set using `fig.text`.

> (2) Can I rotate the color bar?

`cbar_kws={"orientation": "horizontal"}` is the argument for `sns.heatmap` that makes the colorbars horizontal.

Using the code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)

#First

sns.heatmap(flights, ax=ax1, fmt='d', cmap='gist_gray_r', xticklabels = [""], yticklabels = [""], annot = True, cbar_kws={"orientation": "horizontal"})
ax1.set_ylabel('')    
ax1.set_xlabel('')
ax1.set_title('Integral')

#Second

sns.heatmap(flights, ax=ax2, fmt='.2f', cmap='gist_gray_r', xticklabels = [""], yticklabels = [""], annot = True, cbar_kws={"orientation": "horizontal"})
ax2.set_ylabel('')    
ax2.set_xlabel('')
ax2.set_title('Float')

ax1.set_ylabel("Month")
ax1.set_xlabel("Year")
ax2.set_xlabel("Year")

plt.show()
```

This generates this image:

[image]

---

If you wish to have only one big horizontal colorbar you can change the code to the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)

#First

im = sns.heatmap(flights, ax=ax1, fmt='d', cmap='gist_gray_r', xticklabels = [""], yticklabels = [""], annot = True, cbar = False)
ax1.set_ylabel('')    
ax1.set_xlabel('')
ax1.set_title('Integral')

#Second

sns.heatmap(flights, ax=ax2, fmt='.2f', cmap='gist_gray_r', xticklabels = [""], yticklabels = [""], annot = True, cbar = False)
ax2.set_ylabel('')    
ax2.set_xlabel('')
ax2.set_title('Float')

ax1.set_ylabel("Month")
ax1.set_xlabel("Year")
ax2.set_xlabel("Year")

mappable = im.get_children()[0]
plt.colorbar(mappable, ax = [ax1,ax2],orientation = 'horizontal')

plt.show()
```

We are getting the mappable object: `mappable = im.get_children()[0]` and then creating a `plt.colorbar` using this mappable object and `[ax1,ax2]` as the `ax` paramater. I expect this to work every time, it plots the image:

[image]

Comment: I just realised you only want one big horizontal colorbar, I'll edit my answer with this solution.

Comment: I appreciate your quick responses! All of my questions were solved! The really needed figure is the combination of 10 heatmaps and I could make that on the basis of the above code. I can't understand and use mappable object appropriately yet, but I will continue to try that because one big horizontal colorbar is better.
Thank you again.

Comment: @rrkk I'm glad it helped, if it was helpful you should [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) by clicking on the green tick marker near the upvotes.

Comment: I'm ashamed because I sometimes forget to check the green tick mark. I've checked that.